# Xamarin & MVVM How to?

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Hi i'm new to `Xamarin` and I was advised to use pure `MVVM` because my code was a little bit of a mix between `MVVM` and just nothing at all.

I looked at this examples:

1. [Example1](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/)
2. [Example2](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)

But I still can't properly define in my code what is the `Model`, what is the `View` and what is the `ModelView`.

Can you point me to the right structure of my projects following the `MVVM`?

Comment: It looks like you are missing the ViewModels. You have a View (that view holding your ListView) and a Model (StoreModel) but you are just missing a ViewModel that "connects" them. Just create a ViewModel and let your controls. (ListView) bind it's properties and events onto that model and your done

Comment: @Tobias Theel That would be very simple if i hadn't the CustomRenderers which must deal with the bindings themselves, and in case of Android has its own CellView.

Comment: I don't get why that prevents you from binding the view properties onto a viewModel. Could you please explain that part a little more detailed?

Comment: There are a lot of articles about MVVM and implementing MVVM with Xamarin Forms, start from understanding the MVVM it self. Check this out https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm/

Comment: @Tobias Theel I tried to explain a little bit more... is it enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to explain pure MVVM structure with reference example of Employee

PCL :

=>Model : which will contain all your model clases.for example employee.cs

=>View  : which will contain all xaml pages .for example employeeList.xaml etc

=>ViewModel : which will contain all viewmodel. for example employeeViewmodel.cs in which you can defince bindable property,commands  and all other mothods for operation like add,update etc.  now bind this viewmodel to view using bindingContext.

=>DependencyService : define interface which u want to implement in different platform

Android :

=>DependencyService : implement platform specific interface according to your requirement .

=> CustomRenderer : create custom render here for specific requirement.according to platform.

EDIT :

see for example you want to display total no of employees on your view(UI) that keeps changing .

so you can create bindable property EmpCount in viewmodel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. and now you can get set it in any method.

now as you have already set this view model as binding context of page.its value automatically reflects on UI.

Comment: What about the `ContentPage.BindingContext` and the `{Binding Property}` and `BindableProperty` I cant really understand how they are used...

Comment: @Tiago_nes please check my EDIT. and let me know if still you have any confusion

Comment: Same about `ObservableCollection`?
I dont need to Implement `INptifyPropertychanged` when i use the collection rigth?

Comment: it should be actually.but sometimes it dont reflect.so i will suggest you to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and create bindable property for it.for better practice.